# How to hide item from the MainActivity toolbar in a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

In my application I have `Toolbar` in the MainActivity and inside the MainActivity I have a `ViewPager` to show 4 fragment.

The `toolbar` contains some images (`button`).

I want in one of these fragments to hide the image from the `toolbar`.
I wrote the code below, but it hides the image in all the `fragments`.

My code:

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                troy.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }, 50);
    }
}
```

I want to hide it just in my current `fragment`, not all of them.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `addOnPageChangeListener()` of your `ViewPager`

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener(){

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {       

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
         if (position == 0) { // Condition may vary according to your needs...
             troy.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         } else {
             troy.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }
});
```

Comment: Edited the answer. You can utilize `ViewPager`'s functions.

Comment: i write below code. but show me this view in all of fragments

Comment: `public boolean onTabSelected(int position, boolean wasSelected) {

switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        mainViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                        troy.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        mainViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        mainViewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
                        troy.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        break;
}
 return true;`

Comment: can you help me ? please

Comment: You are not setting it to `VISIBLE` again. You have to write `troy.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` to all other case except `0` if want to hid it only if the selected position is `0`. And there is no need to write `mainViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);` anywhere.

Comment: I accept you answer, but i can't upvote. because my vote is low and i can't get you upvote. sorry